# how can i get progress from seekbar?

Tags: java, android

so i want to take progress from seek bar and use it in button method, but its always 0(counter),doesnt work. I tried seekB.getProgress();,seekbar works great...

```
int counter;

seekB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            counter = progress;
            seekbarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    //Randomise Button

    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        int Plength = 6;

        char[] i = new char[Plength];

        List<Character> pass = new ArrayList<>();


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            for (int x = 0; x < Plength; x++) {
                pass.add(azL[rand.nextInt(azL.length)]);
                pass.add(nzL[rand.nextInt(nzL.length)]);
                pass.add(AZL[rand.nextInt(AZL.length)]);

                i[x] = pass.get(rand.nextInt(pass.size()));


            }
            textV.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            pass.clear();
        }

    });
```

if i do textV.setText(String.Valueof(counter)); is going to display 0 all the time.i dont know how to fix it

Comment: show ur counter variable declaration

Comment: @sravs i did it...now?

Comment: your counter should work..between y are u using counter variable? y don't u directly use seekB.getProgress()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change it :

```
@Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            counter = progress;
            seekbarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
}
```

to

```
 @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
counter = progress;
seekbarValue.setText(String.valueOf(new Integer(progress)));
}
```